# get back to application from location services screen

Tags: android, geolocation

I have written following code which takes user to location services screen
but when I click on back button user is taken to home screen of phone and not to the activity from where the intent was fired.

startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

Comment: Have you Finished your location services Activity?

Comment: No I haven't finished the activity

Comment: Just check in your class, somewhere it may called finish() because without it , how can this possible?

Comment: No I haven't called finish(), but somehow its not comming back in my application

Comment: Can you please paste your whole class code.?